# On A Fully-Jewish Town in Spain

Tags: shabbat, minhag, history, jewish-books

I'm preparing a shiur on Golden Age Spain and their minhagim. I remember reading in a historical chronicle (which I could have sworn was the Sefer HaKabbalah of the Raavad HaRishon) about a fully-Jewish town (perhaps Lucena) which learned all day on Shabbat. Upon consulting Ibn Daud I couldn't find the reference. Does this ring a bell for anyone?

Comment: Lucena was home to a large, famous Yeshiva. But 100% Jewish? How would we even know that?

Comment: I heard something similar recently on the seforimchatter podcast on the Rif [here](https://twitter.com/SeforimChatter/status/1447173504026218498). Might have been Lucena, don't remember.

Comment: I vaguely remember something like that from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_of_Tudela